# Helm fetches different "latest" image different than Docker pull's latest image

Tags: docker, kubernetes-helm, docker-registry

A different image is fetched with the same image name Helm does a chart install than if I do an ordinary docker pull. My values.yaml has

```
image:
  repository: gcr.io/rsi-api-test/rsi-api
  tag: latest
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

The only image in the container registry is

```
gcr.io/rsi-api-test/rsi-
api@sha256:473bd9e31df8fd5d5424e11a57cabfd308179c8507683d6b9219c804bb315116
```

But helm somehow finds this image with this code:

```
gcr.io/rsi-api-test/rsi-api@sha256:c5cc78caa54ac4cf855c5fdb6a3448ff74ab641581fcda35d3e4e245c3154766
```

I believe it found some old version and for some reason refuses to get the latest version. Where is the "cached" or local collection of repositories used by helm and how can I force it cleaned?

The registry is a GCP Artifact Registry

```
>helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.17.0", GitCommit:"a690bad98af45b015bd3da1a41f6218b1a451dbe", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.17.0", GitCommit:"a690bad98af45b015bd3da1a41f6218b1a451dbe", GitTreeState:"clean"}
(base)
```

**UPDATE, CHANGED TAGGING**

I edited the tags in the image in GCP, removing both the "latest" and "v0.1.0" tag and adding tag "v1.0.0".  I changed the respective values in the Values.yaml file (above) to

```
image:
  repository: gcr.io/rsi-api-test/rsi-api
  tag: 1.0.0
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Then, I did

```
docker image pull gcr.io/rsi-api-test/rsi-api:latest
```

and confirmed there was no more latest (I'm not sure where it's getting these images from).

then

```
docker run --detached gcr.io/rsi-api-test/rsi-api:1.0.0
```

Docker fetched the 1.0.0 version, and it ran as I expected/wanted.

As for helm, I re-ran helm install, and it didn't work due to an image error (kubectl logs shown below).

```
helm install rsapi
>kubectl logs pod/sullen-lemur-rsiapi-7b8d6d656c-7xmxh
Error from server (BadRequest): container "rsiapi" in pod "sullen-lemur-rsiapi-7b8d6d656c-7xmxh" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image
(base) 
id=woodsman pwd= ~/rsi/backend/rsiapi git=(master) history-id=1494$ 
>^Cep -R "\/v2" * |less
(base) 
id=woodsman pwd= ~/rsi/backend/rsiapi git=(master) history-id=1494$ 
>kubectl describe pod/sullen-lemur-rsiapi-7b8d6d656c-7xmxh
Name:         sullen-lemur-rsiapi-7b8d6d656c-7xmxh
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         gke-helm-cluster-default-pool-7c542461-sdpv/10.128.0.6
Start Time:   Thu, 26 May 2022 23:19:00 -0400
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/instance=sullen-lemur
              app.kubernetes.io/name=rsiapi
              pod-template-hash=7b8d6d656c
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Pending
IP:           10.72.1.13
IPs:
  IP:           10.72.1.13
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/sullen-lemur-rsiapi-7b8d6d656c
Containers:
  rsiapi:
    Container ID:   
    Image:          gcr.io/rsi-api-test/rsi-api:1.0.0
    Image ID:       
    Port:           8080/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Liveness:       http-get http://:http/ delay=60s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:http/ delay=20s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_CONFIG_NAME:      sullen-lemur-rsiapi
      MANAGEMENT_ENDPOINT_RESTART_ENABLED:      true
      SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_RELOAD_ENABLED:   true
      SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_RELOAD_STRATEGY:  refresh
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-fvgg8 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-fvgg8:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  13m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/sullen-lemur-rsiapi-7b8d6d656c-7xmxh to gke-helm-cluster-default-pool-7c542461-sdpv
  Normal   Pulling    12m (x4 over 13m)     kubelet            Pulling image "gcr.io/rsi-api-test/rsi-api:1.0.0"
  Warning  Failed     12m (x4 over 13m)     kubelet            Failed to pull image "gcr.io/rsi-api-test/rsi-api:1.0.0": rpc error: code = NotFound desc = failed to pull and unpack image "gcr.io/rsi-api-test/rsi-api:1.0.0": failed to resolve reference "gcr.io/rsi-api-test/rsi-api:1.0.0": gcr.io/rsi-api-test/rsi-api:1.0.0: not found
  Warning  Failed     12m (x4 over 13m)     kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     11m (x6 over 13m)     kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   BackOff    3m32s (x42 over 13m)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "gcr.io/rsi-api-test/rsi-api:1.0.0"
(base) 
id=woodsman pwd= ~/rsi/backend/rsiapi git=(master) history-id=1495$ 
>helm ls
NAME            REVISION    UPDATED                     STATUS      CHART           APP VERSION NAMESPACE
sullen-lemur    1           Thu May 26 23:19:00 2022    DEPLOYED    rsiapi-0.1.0    1.0         default
```

The same image id was tied up in two SHA codes:

```
> docker image rm 8d0bfa85e8f9
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 8d0bfa85e8f9 
(must be forced) - image is referenced in multiple repositories
```

```
>docker image ls
REPOSITORY                                                             TAG             IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
gcr.io/rsi-api-test/rsi-api                                            latest          8d0bfa85e8f9   10 hours ago    379MB
gcr.io/rsi-api-test/rsi-api                                            v1.0.0          8d0bfa85e8f9   10 hours ago    379MB
```

```
>docker image rm -f 8d0bfa85e8f9
Untagged: gcr.io/rsi-api-test/rsi-api:latest
Untagged: gcr.io/rsi-api-test/rsi-api:v1.0.0
Untagged: gcr.io/rsi-api-test/rsi-api@sha256:473bd9e31df8fd5d5424e11a57cabfd308179c8507683d6b9219c804bb315116
Deleted: sha256:8d0bfa85e8f929221a7c6b66e5fd6008151e496407ed9e74072dd3e02314ad12
```

*BONUS points to suggest a way/policy to increment the version tag in for helm. This is a Github Workflow Maven build of a spring boot application.*

Also, I'm running Helm on my personal Linux machine, but want it to target a GCP cluster. However, I also tried installing helm and using it on a Minikube installation. What do I need to do to make sure I fully switch?

Comment: Do you have a public example of this? The listed image is not accessible for me.

Comment: `latest` doesn't necessarily mean "get the most recent build".  If the node already has an image tagged with `latest` then Kubernetes will use it, even if there's a newer one on the registry.  A usual best practice is to avoid `latest` and similar fixed strings as tag names in your Deployment YAML.